# Which lens spaces are chiral?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, low-dimensional-topology

By chiral, I mean a manifold which does not admit a orientation-reversing self-homeomorphism.

I am curious if the lens space $L(p,q)$ is chiral or not, for varying values of $p$ and $q$. For instance, is $L(3,1)$ chiral?

Comment: a simple search over the net say L(3,1) is chiral

Comment: @janmarqz Is it easy to see why it is so?

Comment: can be read from Seifert Threlfall https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=rsb8zjP0XHoC&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=orientation+reversals+in+lens+space&source=bl&ots=bMaqFVk-6W&sig=3Lsti_oOs_arwlvauVZlfCJgn5k&hl=es-419&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ4eyY9I3cAhUhiFQKHcmEBvwQ6AEIazAH#v=onepage&q=orientation%20reversals%20in%20lens%20space&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 3.22 and Lemma 3.23 in Hempel give $q^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$ as a necessary and sufficient condition for $L(p, q)$ to admit an orientation-reversing homeomorphism. The proof's not particularly difficult but does require a bit of 3-manifold topology (and if you're already familiar with 3-manifold topology, I don't have anything to add to Hempel's proof).

Comment: You mean $-q^2$ is a quadratic residue of $p$?

Comment: No, I mean that $q^2\equiv -1 \pmod{p}$. (The former would just be that $(-1/p) =1$.)

Comment: Oh thanks. Never mind.